# WordPress: Upload images in Media-Library destroyed, pixels messed around

Tags: wordpress

I use the WordPress Media-library to upload images, and distribute form there to other areas where needed. The images do arrive in the library, but there are ‘destroyed’

No mater what size, I had 5Mb, or 100K, .jpg or .png, or the source – web, camera, etc -, all go wrong.

– there are blocks of pixels, like 1/4 of the image, moved around to different positions in that image.

– a horizontal bar, ~ 10% of pic size, moved to the bottom of the image as a gray bar

– sometimes I just get a tiny part of the image as a bar on top of the picture
– thumbnails etc have the same issue.

I can confirm:
– Plenty of disk space at host.
– If I work with cpanel, I can upload any image (type, size) in the Media-library folder; they all look OK, no issues there
They do not show in Media-library GUI due to not proper processed by WordPress I reckon.
– With all this in mind, it must be somewhere in my WP where things go wrong..

WP 4.9.5 Theme 2011

[image]

I hope someone can help!
Many thanks,
Adzy

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and contacted my hosting provider. They confirmed a bug related to POST requests, that was connected to their recent deployment of HTTP/2 on their web accelerators and that caused the image upload bug in WordPress. They disabled HTTP/2, which solved the image upload bug.

Comment: Dear Berliner, thank you for your answer. I will go after them an let this post know if resolved. Cheers ..Adzy